# Getting error when using multiple "\paragraph"s

Tags: paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to make two paragraps one after another using \paragraph:

```latex
\begin{proof}
\paragraph{Case 1}
If $ \mu E_N = \infty $ for some $ N $, then $ \mu E_m = \infty $
for all $ m \geq N $. Also $ \cup E_n \supseteq E_N $. So $ \mu (\cup E_n ) = \infty $.

\paragraph{Case 2}
If $ \mu E_n < \infty $ for all $ n $, then set $ C_1 := E_1, C_n := E_n\setminus E_{n-1} $. Then $ \cup E_n := \sqcup C_n $. By our lemma, $ \mu C_n = \mu E_n - \mu E_{n-1} $. Then 
    \begin{align*}
        \mu (\cup E_n) &= \mu (\sqcup C_n) \\
                       &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu C_n \\
                       &= \lim_{N\to \infty } \sum_{n=1}^N \mu C_n \\
                       &= \lim_{N\to \infty } \mu E_N
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}
```

But pdflatex gives error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.319   \paragraph
                 {Case 2}
```

I tried

```latex
\begin{enumerate}[label=Case(\arabic*)] ... \end{enumerate}
```

as in the error message but the labels didn't align with the rest of the text.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Can you give a fully compilable code?

Comment: `\paragraph` (despite its name) is the 4th level section heading and should only be used after the 3rd level, `\subsubsection` it should never be used inside proofs or other theorem or numbered environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some text before the first `\paragraph`.

On the other hand, I don't see how they are useful, so I provide a different code with fixes to the symbols and the tombstone. Note in particular `\bigcup`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
We divide the proof into two cases.

\paragraph{Case 1}
If $ \mu E_N = \infty $ for some $ N $, then $ \mu E_m = \infty $
for all $ m \geq N $. Also $ \cup E_n \supseteq E_N $. So $ \mu (\cup E_n ) = \infty $.

\paragraph{Case 2}
If $ \mu E_n < \infty $ for all $ n $, then set $ C_1 := E_1, C_n := E_n\setminus E_{n-1} $. 
Then $ \cup E_n := \sqcup C_n $. By our lemma, $ \mu C_n = \mu E_n - \mu E_{n-1} $. Then 
    \begin{align*}
        \mu (\cup E_n) &= \mu (\sqcup C_n) \\
                       &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu C_n \\
                       &= \lim_{N\to \infty } \sum_{n=1}^N \mu C_n \\
                       &= \lim_{N\to \infty } \mu E_N
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
We divide the proof into two cases.

\textbf{Case 1.}
If $ \mu E_N = \infty $ for some $ N $, then $ \mu E_m = \infty $
for all $ m \geq N $. Also $ \bigcup E_n \supseteq E_N $. So $ \mu (\bigcup E_n ) = \infty $.

\textbf{Case 2.}
If $ \mu E_n < \infty $ for all $ n $, then set $ C_1 := E_1, C_n := E_n\setminus E_{n-1} $. 
Then $ \bigcup E_n := \bigsqcup C_n $. By our lemma, $ \mu C_n = \mu E_n - \mu E_{n-1} $. Then 
    \begin{align*}
        \mu \Bigl(\bigcup E_n\Bigr) &= \mu \Bigl(\bigsqcup C_n\Bigr) \\
                       &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu C_n \\
                       &= \lim_{N\to \infty } \sum_{n=1}^N \mu C_n \\
                       &= \lim_{N\to \infty } \mu E_N \qedhere
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Got it, thanks. I also tried ```textbf{Case 1}``` before but since i didn't put text before that, "Case 1"  would get placed rigth next to "Proof". I decided to add an empty line but it was advised not to add empty line. So i tried ```\paragpraphs```. (I was trying to keep lecture notes as original as possible but this is an acceptable modification)

Comment: @vobopel450 For just `\textbf{Case 1}` on a new line, just add `\mbox{}` after `\begin{proof}`. But I see no reason to.

Comment: Just hope no one increases `tocdepth`.

Answer (score 1):

To align labels of `enumerate`  at the left margin, just use this code:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
......
\begin{enumerate}[label=Case(\arabic*), wide=0pt, font=\bfseries] 
\item ...
......... 
\end{enumerate}
```